# When building AnimatedList, how does "insertItem" work?

Tags: flutter, animation

In particular, I'm not understanding how the `insertItem` function knows the item to add to `_animatedList` in the excerpt below, given its only argument is the index location.

What is going on here?

```
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> listKey;
  final dynamic removedItemBuilder;
  final List<E> _items;

  AnimatedListState get _animatedList => listKey.currentState;

  void insert(int index, E item) {
    _items.insert(index, item);
    _animatedList.insertItem(index);
  }
```

Above excerpt from the following source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `insertItem` and `removeItem` just cues the `AnimatedList` to **animate at `index`**. For example in your code above, if you remove the line

`_animatedList.insertItem(index);`

Your item will be added to the `_items` list but nothing will animate in the List (no UI change), i.e. the animation knows nothing about the item added to your list it just knows at which `index` to animate

Comment: `Both insertItem and removeItem just cues the AnimatedList to animate at index.`  

In that case, what's the difference between `insertItem` and `removeItem` if both serve to animate at index?

Comment: `insertItem` is for `animating in` and `removeItem` is for `animating out` the object, the actual difference is in the `animation` parameter in the `itemBuilder` property of the `AnimatedList`. So that `animation` property is going "forward" in `insertItem` and "backwards" in `removeItem`

Answer (score 1):

The `insertItem` method is used to add the index of the new item to the `AnimatedList`. And every time this method is executed, it triggers the animation to run.

From the AnimatedList class **(animated_list.dart)** it provides the explanation below:

```
  /// The [AnimatedListItemBuilder] index parameter indicates the item's
  /// position in the list. The value of the index parameter will be between 0
  /// and [initialItemCount] plus the total number of items that have been
  /// inserted with [AnimatedListState.insertItem] and less the total number of
  /// items that have been removed with [AnimatedListState.removeItem].
```

Also on the same class, there is this part of the code that shows how everything comes together

```
  Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
    final _ActiveItem outgoingItem = _activeItemAt(_outgoingItems, itemIndex);
    if (outgoingItem != null) {
      return outgoingItem.removedItemBuilder(
        context,
        outgoingItem.controller.view,
      );
    }

    final _ActiveItem incomingItem = _activeItemAt(_incomingItems, itemIndex);
    final Animation<double> animation = incomingItem?.controller?.view ?? kAlwaysCompleteAnimation;
    return widget.itemBuilder(
      context,
      _itemIndexToIndex(itemIndex),
      animation,
    );
  }
```

Before the animation is executed, the value of the index is picked from `_incomingItems` which seems to be equivalent to `_items`

I suppose the main role of the `AnimatedList` is to animate but it requires data to actually know where and what to position. So instead of having 2 lists holding the same data, `_items` and `_animatedList`,  `_animatedList` holds the indexes and depends on `_items` to get the value to display in each position.